# need java code to commit one svn repository from another svn repository

Tags: svn

I have a local SVN repository and an onsite svn repository.i would be updating the local svn repository with my code changes.And i want to commit all the updated files in local repository to onsite svn repository using a scheduled job.This job can run once a day.
Can you please guide me as to how to write a JAVA code for this scenario.i am using Tortoise SVN.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check for SVNCommitClient and SVNUpdateClient. I think that will solve ur purpose. Please use the mentioned libraries and copy your files from updated repository to other repository and invoke SVNCommit.

Hope this helps.